# How to format Hard drive NTFS and convert it to FAT32?

Tags: ntfs, partitioning, format, fat32

As the question, I have some NTFS HD in my ubuntu server, some has few partitions, I would like to fully format them, create only 1 partition and convert it to FAT32.

Thanks

Comment: Not a particularly good idea. FAT32 is really only for small partitions, it does not support files large than 4GB nor has journal. If dual booting with Windows NTFS is ok, but if only Linux use ext4. Whatever you do, make sure you have good backups as conversion will erase data.

Comment: thanks, i thought fat32 was the way to go with linux, any tutorials you may have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [oldfred indicates here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113644/how-to-format-hard-drive-ntfs-and-convert-it-to-fat32#comment1838568_1113644) FAT32 has some serious limitations such as the maximum file size is 4 GB and the maximum partition size is 2 TB. FAT32 also performs slower compared to your current NTFS partitions.

Drives that are going to be used only under Ubuntu should be formatted using the ext3/ext4 file system (depending on which version of Ubuntu you use (Recent versions use ext4) and whether you need Linux backwards compatibility in which case ext3 would be a better choice). For sharing between Ubuntu and Windows, FAT32 is often recommended, but NTFS outperforms FAT32 and isn't as limited. If you are new to file systems and partitioning, please do some preliminary research on the two before you 
make a choice.

Since formatting or changing the partitioning scheme will result in lost data (granted recoverable in many cases with advanced tools) it's important to [backup any critical data](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem) before you start changing partitioning schemes and creating new filesystems. If you are using your partitions under Ubuntu only it's wise to be aware of the differences between ext3 and ext4 prior to making a choice. There's some great information on [ext4 here](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Howto) that mentions some of the differences between ext3 and ext4. Of special interest are multiblock and delayed allocation which boost performance when using ext4 and aren't available for ext3. As far as tutorials go since you've backed up your data to avoid loss, there's no reason you can't use the same [approach you would with a new drive.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive)

Sources:
Experience
https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=1287

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Howto